# PHP Regex to match Javascript date output

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find a PHP regex to find Javascript date output in JSON strings. I'll read all JSON objects from a database and convert each string into `DD/MM/YYYY` format.

For example `Tue Sep 24 2019 14:12:51 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)`

I almost made it, probably it is not any good but could not finish it as well :(

`[a-zA-Z]{3} [a-zA-Z]{3} \d{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} GMT\D\d{4}`

The date might also be `Tue Sep 24 2019 14:12:51 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)` so I need to find anything in parentheses as well.

The JSON object can have multiple dates inside it so I'll need to find and replace all of them.

Thank you!

Comment: how about removing the parenthesis part with a substring and then using `new \DateTime(yourString)`, you can then use the DateTime class to format into the way you want it

Comment: To remove them I'll need to find them, the JSON string unfortunately contains some HTML data in it and users added content with parenthesis as well. But then I can search for known time zones and remove them completely first then apply the regex?

Comment: I throught you had a strings wich contained only the date. I think if you keep your current regex to get all the dates and create a DateTime for each date found it should works (as long as the date string is valid)

Comment: Thank you @jonatjano but I cannot select the whole string because of the parenthesis :( I am looking a regex like find anything in parenthesis as well, so I can parse that string into my format and replace it.

Comment: then try this one `[a-zA-Z]{3} [a-zA-Z]{3} \d{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} GMT\D\d{4} \(.+\)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`((?:[a-zA-Z]{3} ){2}\d{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} GMT[+-]\d{4}) \(([^\)\n]+)\)`

This regex will select the entire string, and will also separately capture both the date string and whatever is in the parenthesis for you to process on your own.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/yVRKYU/4/)